# Push list of elements to component in React

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to build a sidebar component similar to the one in this image: 
Instead of passing the child components as Objects with text values through the props, I'd like to create a separate component for each key-value pair in each element in the list. For example: if the list has 3 elements, there should be 3 components for each element in the list.

Here is my code so far:

#### sidebarcomponents.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function SidebarComponents({ name, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  const style = {
    cursor: 'pointer'
  }

  return (
    <div
      name={name}
      title={title}
      style={style}
      onClick={() => {
        if (onSelect) onSelect(name)
      }}
    >
                   
    </div>
  )
}

export default SidebarComponents
```

#### sidebar.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import SidebarComponents from '../../components/Sidebar1/Sidebar'

function Sidebar({ onChange }) {
  const [selectedComponent, setSelectedComponent] = useState({
    componentsName: [
      { name: 'Overview', title: 'Overview' },
      { name: 'SPO2', title: 'SPO2' }
    ]
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedComponent.componentsName.map(componentsName => {
        return (
          <SidebarComponents
            name={componentsName.name}
            title={componentsName.title}
          />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

How can I change my code to map a list child components rather than a list of objects that represent them?

I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: Define your problem.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar my problem is that i'm not able to do it the code is wrong and its not giving me what i want, i have a list that contains name and title and i want to create a component for each element in the list( so if i have overview and alert for example it will create two components one for overview with the name overview and title overview and one with alerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shubham-khatri's answer is correct: you need to include the text inside the component.

Below is a more in-depth solution using [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) and [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) -- I suggest reading the linked docs as hooks and render props are awesome.. Note that hooks are only available starting with React 16.8.

In simple terms, in the below example, the sidebar renders using the `render` prop provided by the parent component: `App`. In the `render` prop for the `SidebarComponent`, the function says to render a `Title` and a `Name` component. The `name` from the `map` function is used as the argument for the `onClick` handler, and to set `selected` to `true` or `false`, without having to pass the selected component object to the sidebar.

If you want to provide a master list of components the sidebar can render, and then pass which of that set should render in the props, then you will have to filter the `componentsName` array such that only the ones provided in the props for `SidebarComponent`.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

/**
 * Title component
 * @param {string=''} props.title
 */
const Title = ({ title = '' }) => <h2>{title}</h2>

/**
 * Name component
 * @param {string=''} props.name
 */
const Name = ({ name = '' }) => <div>{name}</div>

/**
 * SidebarComponent styles
 */
const style = {
  cursor: 'pointer'
}

/**
 * SidebarComponent classes
 */
const classes = {
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
  }
}

/**
 * @func SidebarComponent
 * @param {string=''} name
 * @param {function} onClick
 * @param {boolean=false} selected
 * @param {string=''} title
 * @returns {React.Node} react component that returns a div
 *  containing two other components: Title and Name
 */
const SidebarComponent = ({
  name = '',
  onClick,
  selected = false,
  title = ''
}) => (
  <div
    onClick={onClick && onClick}
    style={{
      ...style,
      ...(selected ? classes.selected : {})
    }}
  >
    <Title title={title} />
    <Name name={name} />
  </div>
)

/**
 * @func Sidebar
 * @param {Array[{title: string, name: string}]} componentsName an
 *  arry of components to render inside the sidebar, as SidebarComponents
 * @param {function} renderProp render function that dictates
 *  what to render inside of the sidebar
 * @returns {Node} returns the calling of the renderProp function
 */
const Sidebar = ({ componentsName, render }) => {
  const [selectedComponentName, setSelectedComponentName] = React.useState(null)
  const handleClick = name => setSelectedComponentName(name)
  return (
    <div id="sidebar">
      {render({
        selectedComponentName,
        handleClick
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

/**
 * An array of the components to render inside the Sidebar
 */
const componentsName = [
  { name: 'Overview', title: 'Overview' },
  { name: 'SPO2', title: 'SPO2' }
]

/**
 * @func App
 * @returns {React.Node} a react component that renders the sidebar
 */
const App = () => (
  <Sidebar
    render={({ selectedComponentName, handleClick }) =>
      componentsName.map(({ name, ...props }, index) => (
        <SidebarComponent
          selected={name === selectedComponentName}
          key={`sidebar-component-${index}`}
          onClick={() => handleClick(name)}
          {...{
            name,
            ...props
          }}
        />
      ))
    }
  />
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

#### Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-wnxer?file=/index.js

In this demo, you can click on either the menu item, and see the selected item change background-color to green.

Comment: @mouhamad you're welcome. Note that this is probably overkill for your use case. the `Title` and `Name` components don't need to exist as they're written currently -- they can be combined into the single `SidebarComponent`. It's a useful pattern to learn though -- make sure to read up on hooks and renderProps when you can! 

Answer (score 1):

You need to render the name within the DIV inside the component and not pass it on as a prop to div like

```
function SidebarComponents({name,title,selected,onSelect}) {

    const style={
        cursor: "pointer"
    };

    return (
        <div 
            title = {title}
            style={style}
            onClick={() => {if (onSelect) onSelect(name)}}
        >
           {name}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Also pass on the onSelect and selected prop to the SidebarComponents when you are rendering it after mapping